# how can i bring up a download button when a file is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I think my question is really simple for javascript developers, but as I am a backend developer I have to solve some javascript stuff.

My question:
I want a download button to show up when a particular file is clicked, using jquery.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" style="margin:0 3px" onclick="delete_file();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</button>
```

I have this javascript:

```
function download_file() {
    var fileId = $($(".contextMenuFile.activeFile") 
    [0]).attr("data-file")
    var url = '/downloadFile/' + fileId
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = url;
    link.click();  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add button to HTML.
- Wrap it inside another div
- Set div style to `display:none`
- Change div style with jQuery's `show`.

```js
// To show button
$("#button_show_starter").click(function() {
  $(".button_wrapper").show("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

// To hide button if visible when clicking on other elements
$("body").click(function(e) {
  const target = $(e.target);
  if (!target.is('#button_show_starter') && !target.is('.pull-right')) {
    $('.button_wrapper').hide();
  }
});

function delete_file() {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="button_wrapper" style="display: none">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" style="margin:0 3px" onclick="delete_file();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</button>
</div>

<p id="button_show_starter">SHOW ME THE BUTTON</p>
<div>You can tap here</div>
<div>Or here to hide button if vibisble</div>
</body>
```

[jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: can you show me the reverse way if it is clicked outside of this id = "button_show_starter" this buttons should be disabled

Comment: can you please explain the code i need to integrate more on this

Comment: also in this code you need some edit like if we click on the button the button is disabled please resolve it

Comment: how can i add two classes in !target.is('*HERE*')

Comment: `if (!target.is('.class1') && !target.is('.class2'))`, check the code in the answer. You can add many classes here just by adding `&& !target.is('.class3')` and so on.